# How can I sort values of type List[(Int, Int)] in Map?

Tags: scala, sorting

I have this Map

```
Map(pop -> List((600,1), (2500,4)), classic -> List((500,0), (150,2), (800,3)))
```

And this is the result I want:

```
Map(pop -> List((2500,4),(600,1)), classic -> List((800,3),(500,0),(150,2)))
```

I want it to be sorted by the first index in `List[(Int, Int)]`, the value of map.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: `val newmap = mymap.map{case (k,v) => k -> v.sortBy(-_._1)}`

Comment: I struggled all day to solve this problem.. 
I learned to use `case` thank you! @jwvh

Answer (score 0):

You may use `mapValues`:

```
myMap.mapValues(_.sortBy(-_._1))
```

or:

```
myMap.mapValues(_.sorted.reverse)
```

Comment: `mapValues()` deprecated in Scala 2.13.